# angular - @angular/common without NPM

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to use the ng-template directive in my code to be able to show a div after a button click event but I cannot get it to work since  I need to have the angular/common library. I tried to reference it by adding a script tag

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@angular/common@11.0.2/bundles/common.umd.min.js" integrity="sha256-+HBVhNZwWCgkN0Z0tvWyjqjm+yI9F/szNt3Yz4/0/ws=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

But every time I test my app, the following error appears in the console.

```
common.umd.min.js:35 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'InjectionToken' of undefined
```

I am stuck and don't know how can I be able to use the ng-template directive

HTML (index.html):

```
<ng-template>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Edit or Delete an Evangelist</h2>
        <form name="userEditForm">
            <p>person id:     <input type="text" id="name" ng-model="userEdit.personid" disabled /></p>
            <p>name:     <input type="text" id="name" ng-model="userEdit.name" /></p>
            <p>location: <input type="text" id="location" ng-model="userEdit.location" /></p>
            <button id="btn-edit-evangelist" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="editName(userEdit)">Save</button>
            <button id="btn-canceledit-evangelist" class="btn btn-default btn" ng-click="delName(userEdit);">Delete User</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="isEdit">
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Angular (main-app.js):

```
"use strict";

angular.module('MainApp', [
])


.controller("MainController", function ($scope, $http) {

    //initialize scope variables
    $scope.user = {
        name: function (theName) {
            if (angular.isDefined(theName)) {
                $scope._name = theName;
            }
            return $scope._name;
        }(),
        location: function (theLocation) {
            if (angular.isDefined(theLocation)) {
                $scope._location = theLocation;
            }
            return $scope._location;
        }()
    };


    function redirectToEdit(user) {
        this.isEdit = !this.isEdit;

        var id = user.personid;

        $http.get('https://webapimongodb.herokuapp.com/api/name/' + id, {
            params: { personid: user.personid, name: user.name, location: user.location },
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        })
            .success(function (res) {
                console.log(res);
                $scope.userEdit.personid = res.personid;
                $scope.userEdit.name = res.Name;
                $scope.userEdit.location = res.Location;
            });

    }


})
```

Will it be possible to have the @angular/common module referenced via a script tag or do I need to have it referenced via NPM?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is the version being used.

The code you provided is written in `Angular.js` code and `@angular/common` is an `Angular` module

To get your code working you need this instead

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.8.0/angular.min.js"></script>
```

[Here you can find the Angular.js docs](https://angularjs.org/), which, by the way, is deprecated.

And [this article explains the difference](https://www.techaheadcorp.com/blog/angular-vs-angularjs/) among Angular and Angular.js

Comment: I added that script tag but I still can't make ng-template and *ngIf (toggle div show/hide) to work.

Comment: @Joseph both *ngIf and <ng-template> are `Angular` syntax, not `Angular.js`. Here you can find the docs with the old syntax for ngIf (ng-if) https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf . There is no directive as ng-template in Angular.js